# Man wakes up from car accident in the future

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, novel

Trying to find a novel or maybe short story where a man in the 1950s or 60s wakes up after a car accident in a future rehabilitation center. He is angry and hurts or kills someone and they treat him as if his anger is a mental illness. His primary contact is a woman unconcerned with nudity. Sex is not taboo.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this? Also, why did you add the [robert-a-heinlein] tag? Do you believe he was the author?

Comment: [Immortality, Inc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immortality,_Inc.) shares some of the tropes with this

Comment: The Age Of The Pussyfoot? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Age_of_the_Pussyfoot

Comment: @sueelleker that's an answer, not a comment.

Comment: Nudity and sex are not taboos are a recurring trope of Heinlein.

Comment: Criggie; I wasn't 100% sure it was right, and I couldn't think of any more details to add.

Comment: _The Kin of Ata Are Waiting for You_ by Dorothy Bryant is what I thought of, but not all details seems to match.

Answer (score 10):

This could be [Robert Heinlein's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robert_A._Heinlein) first novel (not published in his lifetime), [For Us, The Living](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/For_Us,_the_Living).

- The protagonist, Perry Nelson, dies in a car crash in 1939, but his mind somehow is transferred into the body of a man from the year 2086--the future man, "Gordon 755-82", had engaged in a practice called "voluntary abdication" or "suicide by willing not to live", which apparently left his body vacant for Perry's mind to take over.
- He's taken in by an actress named Diana, who is unconcerned with being seen walking around nude, as per future customs (casual sex and polyamory are also the norm in this society).
- He doesn't wake up in a rehabilitation center, instead he wakes up outside in a snow storm and is immediately helped by Diana. But he does later fall in love with Diana and fights one of her actor friends out of jealousy, which results in him being taken to a rehabilitation center since this type of sexual jealousy is seen as a primitive atavism.

Comment: Yeah, that was going to be my answer, Heinlein's godawful first novel. I tried to read it once but couldn't keep from putting it down.